# Inline assembly in C++ fail?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Alright so basically I wrote an assembly function to detect if a certain process is present during run-time. I'm not quite getting the inline assembly to the point that even though I wrapped the assembly code with the asm wrapper it still detects the inner code as C code ... basically it goes a little something like this:

```
__inline bool isProcLoaded()
{
    _asm
    {
        mov ah, 0x48
        int     0x68 ; After compiling it breaks on this line, the 'int' is highlighted
        cmp ax ...
    }
}
```

What is the issue here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not quite clear what your problem is? It won't compile? Or it gives a run time error?
(The syntax highlight issue where the editor misinterprets int as a c keyword doesn't seem like it would cause any actual issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would probably be because [`int`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)) is an interrupt instruction which is rarely useful in user mode nowadays because most interrupts are privileged ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10457296/2802841)).

Without more details I can't tell what are you trying to achieve here, though after searching around the beginning looks similar to a method for detecting SoftICE debugger and that code is pretty ancient (DOS and early Windows era) so it seems only reasonable that on modern OS you get an `0xC0000005` `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` exception.

Comment: Even so, shouldn't it just skip the interrupt since it's not directly calling to 0x80? In any case, how can I make it so that it reverts this in another way and still continues to process the rest of my code? Would a luhn sequence work in this case?

Comment: OP - I don't think you understand what int does. It does 2 things. It changes the processor state into a privileged state and jumps to the Software Interrupt Vector. Execution is no longer under the control of the current process. It is now up to the OS the decide how things proceed from here.

Comment: So wherever I point the int to from there the OS decides what to do next? That makes sense.

Comment: Updated the answer a bit.

Comment: The `int` instruction is highly useful for certain things - even (!) in userland. That's because you can "inject" traps with it, and that way interact with a debugger. It's not a common thing to do, agreed, but that's not a justification for the inline assembler to not support it.