# exact control flow with int assembler instruction in C, and the resulting segfault

Tags: c, intel

Consider this totally stupid code:

```cpp
int main() { __asm__("int $0x2"); }
```

This causes a segfault when run. `2` is code for NMI in intel's IDT (Section 6.3.1 [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html)).

I am curious on why this segfaults though? What exactly is the control flow which will eventually cause it to segfault?

Also pasting section 6.3.3 of the manual here:

> **6.3.3 Software-Generated Interrupts**
>   The INT n instruction permits interrupts to be generated from within software by supplying an interrupt vector
>   number as an operand. For example, the INT 35 instruction forces an implicit call to the interrupt handler for interrupt 35.
>   Any of the interrupt vectors from 0 to 255 can be used as a parameter in this instruction. If the processor’s
>   predefined NMI vector is used, however, the response of the processor will not be the same as it would be from an
>   NMI interrupt generated in the normal manner. If vector number 2 (the NMI vector) is used in this instruction, the
>   NMI interrupt handler is called, but the processor’s NMI-handling hardware is not activated.
>   Interrupts generated in software with the INT n instruction cannot be masked by the IF flag in the EFLAGS register.

Comment: IS this even allowed from user-space?

Comment: @EugeneSh. posted a section from the manual. 'technically' this is allowed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457296/int-instruction-from-user-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gate in the idt contains a *descriptor privilege level* (DPL) which is the largest *caller privilege level* (CPL) which is permitted to invoke this entry.  A real NMI, which is caused by an electrical signal on the cpu, provides an artificial CPL of 0.   In this way, the kernel does not have to differentiate between real signals and fake ones.

System services which are invoked via an *int xx* will have a numerically larger DPL to permit the instruction to *open* the gate with an instruction.  Depending upon your kernel, it is possible that int 3 (breakpoint), 4 (overflow), and 5 (bounds) will work as direct opcodes to facilitate debugging, the "into" and "bounds" opcodes respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You have found a kernel bug. Your program is trying to perform a CPU operation (`int 2`) that is forbidden to user-space programs, not an invalid memory access.  Therefore, it should have been sent a `SIGILL` (Illegal instruction) signal, not a `SIGSEGV` signal.

The reason for the bug is probably that this particular forbidden operation is reported to the operating system with a "#GP fault" instead of a "#UD fault" (in the terms used by the x86 architecture manual).  #GP faults are also used to report invalid memory accesses, and whoever wrote the code to map that to a signal didn't bother making a distinction between "actual invalid memory access" and "improper use of `int` reported with #GP".  I observe this bug as well, on both Linux and NetBSD, so it must be an easy mistake to make.

When you're debugging a problem involving signals, it is often helpful to establish a signal handler for the troublesome signal, using `sigaction` with `SA_SIGINFO` in the flags.  When you set `SA_SIGINFO`, the handler receives two additional arguments that provide detailed information about the signal.  You don't have to *use* those arguments in the signal handler; instead what you do is run the program under a debugger, allow the signal to be delivered, and then inspect the details in the debugger.  Here's a modification to your program that does that:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
void handler(int s, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    pause();
}
int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGBUS,  &sa, 0);
    sigaction(SIGFPE,  &sa, 0);
    sigaction(SIGILL,  &sa, 0);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);
    sigaction(SIGSYS,  &sa, 0);
    sigaction(SIGTRAP, &sa, 0);
    asm("int $0x2");
}
```

(The `uc` argument is a pointer to a `ucontext_t`, but that type is declared in `<ucontext.h>`, not `<signal.h>`, so the spec says you must define the handler to take a third argument of type `void *` and then cast it if you want to use it.)

I set up the handler for *all* of the signals corresponding to fatal, synchronous CPU exceptions, because why not.  The `pause` is just to make execution stop indefinitely inside the handler, so I can hit control-C to break into the debugger and the signal frame will be available.

Here's what I get on Linux:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7eb4af4 in __libc_pause ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pause.c:29
#1  0x000055555555516d in handler (s=11, si=0x7fffffffd830, uc=0x7fffffffd700)
    at test.c:5
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  main () at test.c:14
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x000055555555516d in handler (s=11, si=0x7fffffffd830, uc=0x7fffffffd700)
    at test.c:5
5       pause();
(gdb) p *si
$1 = {si_signo = 11, si_errno = 0, si_code = 128, __pad0 = 0, _sifields = {
    _pad = {0 <repeats 28 times>}, _kill = {si_pid = 0, si_uid = 0}, _timer = {
      si_tid = 0, si_overrun = 0, si_sigval = {sival_int = 0, 
        sival_ptr = 0x0}}, _rt = {si_pid = 0, si_uid = 0, si_sigval = {
        sival_int = 0, sival_ptr = 0x0}}, _sigchld = {si_pid = 0, si_uid = 0, 
      si_status = 0, si_utime = 0, si_stime = 0}, _sigfault = {si_addr = 0x0, 
      si_addr_lsb = 0, _bounds = {_addr_bnd = {_lower = 0x0, _upper = 0x0}, 
        _pkey = 0}}, _sigpoll = {si_band = 0, si_fd = 0}, _sigsys = {
      _call_addr = 0x0, _syscall = 0, _arch = 0}}}
(gdb) p *(ucontext_t *)uc
$2 = {uc_flags = 7, uc_link = 0x0, uc_stack = {ss_sp = 0x0, ss_flags = 0, 
    ss_size = 0}, uc_mcontext = {gregs = {0, 0, 8, 582, 93824992235632, 
      140737488346656, 0, 0, 11, 140737488345936, 140737488346432, 0, 0, 0, 
      140737352200658, 140737488346272, 93824992235964, 66050, 
      12103423998558259, 18, 13, 0, 0}, fpregs = 0x7fffffffd8c0, 
    __reserved1 = {0, 1, 140737354129808, 140737488345320, 140737353799024, 
      140737354129808, 8455580781, 140737354130672}}, uc_sigmask = {__val = {
      0, 11, 128, 0 <repeats 13 times>}}, __fpregs_mem = {cwd = 0, swd = 0, 
    ftw = 0, fop = 0, rip = 140737488346656, rdp = 0, mxcsr = 895, 
    mxcr_mask = 0, _st = {{significand = {0, 0, 0, 0}, exponent = 0, 
        __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 0}}, {significand = {8064, 0, 65535, 0}, 
        exponent = 0, __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 0}}, {significand = {0, 0, 0, 
          0}, exponent = 0, __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 0}}, {significand = {0, 
          0, 0, 0}, exponent = 0, __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 0}}, {
        significand = {0, 0, 0, 0}, exponent = 0, __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 
          0}}, {significand = {0, 0, 0, 0}, exponent = 0, __glibc_reserved1 = {
          0, 0, 0}}, {significand = {0, 0, 0, 0}, exponent = 0, 
        __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 0}}, {significand = {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        exponent = 0, __glibc_reserved1 = {0, 0, 0}}}, _xmm = {{element = {0, 
          0, 0, 0}} <repeats 16 times>}, __glibc_reserved1 = {
      0 <repeats 18 times>, 1179670611, 836, 7, 0, 832, 0}}, __ssp = {0, 0, 0, 
    3}}
```

The `siginfo_t` structure is basically useless; it has `si_code == 128`, which means  "this signal was generated by the kernel but we're not going to tell you anything else about it," and all the other fields are zero.  I consider this to be *another* kernel bug.

The `ucontext_t` structure is more useful; in particular

```
(gdb) p/x ((ucontext_t *)uc)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]
$3 = 0x5555555551bc
```

This is the address of the instruction that caused the signal.  If I disassemble `main`...

```
(gdb) disas main
...
0x00005555555551b7: callq  0x555555555030 <sigaction@plt>
0x00005555555551bc: int    $0x2
0x00005555555551be: mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00005555555551c3: leaveq 
0x00005555555551c4: retq
```

... I see that the instruction that caused the signal is indeed the `int $0x2`.

On NetBSD I get something slightly different:

```
(gdb) p *si
$1 = { si_pad = "[garbage]", _info = {
         _signo = 11, _code = 2, _errno = 0, _pad = 0, _reason = {
           _rt = {_pid = -146410395, _uid = 32639, _value = {sival_int = 4,
          sival_ptr = 0x4}}, _child = {_pid = -146410395, _uid = 32639,
        _status = 4, _utime = 0, _stime = 0}, _fault = {
        _addr = 0x7f7ff745f465 <__sigemptyset14>, _trap = 4, _trap2 = 0,
        _trap3 = 0}, _poll = {_band = 140187586131045, _fd = 4}}}}
```

This siginfo_t has actually been filled out.  si_code 2 for a SIGSEGV is SEGV_ACCERR ("Invalid permissions for mapped object") which is not nonsense.  There is not enough information in the headers or the manpages for me to understand what `_trap = 4` means, or why `_addr` is pointing to an address somewhere inside the C library, and I don't feel like source-diving the NetBSD kernel today. `;-)`

Also for reasons I don't feel like investigating today, gdb on NetBSD doesn't have access to the definition of `ucontext_t` (even though I explicitly included ucontext.h) so I had to dump it out raw:

```
(gdb) p *(ucontext_t *)uc
No symbol "ucontext_t" in current context.
(gdb) x/40xg uc
0x7f7fffffd7b0: 0x00000000000a000d      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd7c0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd7d0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd7e0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000005
0x7f7fffffd7f0: 0x00007f7fffffdb50      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd800: 0x00007f7ff7483a0a      0x0000000000000002
0x7f7fffffd810: 0x000000000000000d      0x00007f7ff749f340
0x7f7fffffd820: 0x0000000000000246      0x00007f7fffffdb90
0x7f7fffffd830: 0x00007f7ffffffdea      0x00007f7ff511a4c0
0x7f7fffffd840: 0x00007f7ffffffdea      0x00007f7fffffdb70
0x7f7fffffd850: 0x00007f7fffffffe0      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd860: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd870: 0x000000000000003f      0x00007f7ff748003f
0x7f7fffffd880: 0x0000000000000004      0x0000000000000012
0x7f7fffffd890: 0x0000000000400af5      0x000000000000e033  <---
0x7f7fffffd8a0: 0x0000000000010246      0x00007f7fffffdb50
0x7f7fffffd8b0: 0x000000000000e02b      0x00007f7ff7ffd0c0
0x7f7fffffd8c0: 0x000000000000037f      0x0000000000000000
0x7f7fffffd8d0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000ffbf00001f80
0x7f7fffffd8e0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   ...
   0x0000000000400af0 <+166>:   callq  0x400810 <__sigaction14@plt>
   0x0000000000400af5 <+171>:   int    $0x2
   0x0000000000400af7 <+173>:   leaveq 
   0x0000000000400af8 <+174>:   retq
```

The only address within the memory region pointed to by `uc` that bears any correspondence with the text of the program is `0x0000000000400af5`, which is, again, the address of the `int` instruction.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer, but I think @mevets provided the key insight that i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't fault with `#UD` when the descriptor privilege isn't sufficient.  `int` isn't an illegal instruction, the faulty part is trying to use a bad software-interrupt number.  That's why it makes sense to deliver SIGSEGV, or at least *not* SIGILL.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, when I said "this is probably a quirk of how x86 processors report ..." I meant "I figure whoever wrote the x86-specific trap handling code in Linux and NetBSD mapped all `#GP` faults to SIGSEGV without thinking about it much." (1/2)

Comment: @PeterCordes In terms of the fine typology of machine faults that's defined by the [table of `si_code` constants in XBD `signal.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) (search for "values of si_code"), though, SIGILL with `si_code` set to ILL_ILLTRP or ILL_PRVOPC makes a lot more sense than SIGSEGV. There's no meaningful "address of faulting memory reference" to set `si_addr` to if you call this a SIGSEGV, for instance.